# Is there any way to build trusted certificate for macro for free?

Tags: vba, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

I build one using Microsoft tools but its says "Untrusted cerificate". which is useless.

Is there any way to build trusted certificate for macro for free?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a certificate that is only valid for the PC on which it is created, although it can be exported and trusted elsewhere. Will that be adequate?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/digitally-sign-a-macro-project-HA001231781.aspx

Comment: as i mention above i already done with this. But its not working.

Comment: It works for me on every computer every time and for several years at this stage. Are you sure you chose a trusted location for the certificate?

Comment: yes, I stored it under "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store.